# Does Sql Azure charge by database or database server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've currently got a "Web" edition SQL Azure server with on database on it.  I want to put another database on there but am unsure how the costing works.  Will I need to pay the £9.99 per database or database server?

Does it make more sense just to set up a couple of different schemas in my existing database to try and reduce costs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pay per database. Creating schemas may make sense if cost is your concern. I have seen this done multiple times. However keep in mind that a few SQL Server/Azure features are schema independent. For example user-defined statistics and roles are schema independent. So as long as you don't use these features you should be good with a schema-based separation.